# Geometric meaning of twist

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, geometric-representation-theory

It is sometimes the case that a Galois representation or a motive acquires a desirable property only after a twist by a character, usually a Tate twist. The latest example of this I have come across is the recent paper of Petrov in which it is shown that any geometrically irreducible $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_p$-local system on a smooth variety over a $p$-adic field becomes de Rham after twist by a Galois character. [https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.13372]

What is the underlying geometric reason for this, if any? That is to say, what effect does a twist have geometrically, or is it an entirely cohomogical "normalization" factor?  If the latter, is there a broader context or theory within which such normalization can be understood?

Comment: I strongly suspect that the twist in the paper by Petrov is *not* a Tate twist in general, because being "de Rham up to a Tate twist" is equivalent to being de Rham; so if Petrov's twist were a Tate twist, he could just get rid of it entirely and simplify the statements.

Comment: @DavidLoeffler, No, it is not a Tate twist, and I did not say it was.

Comment: I think maybe a better comparison for Petrov's "non-Tate" twist is the result described in this question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23009/if-the-tensor-product-of-two-representations-are-crystalline-are-the-original-r

Comment: I suspect that you may be conflating two different ways in which twists can arise. Tate twists are relevant because they allow you to go back from "motives" to "effective motives" (which is pretty much true by definition, since we get motives from effective motives by adjointing the Tate motive as an inverse of the Lefschetz motive). This is rather separate from the role of non-Hodge--Tate twists in Petrov, and in the question I linked, which is related to the fact that it is very easy to write down 1-dimensional non-HT Galois reps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117777/discussion-between-david-loeffler-and-kan).

Comment: Tate twists are used to achieve $\mathbb{P}^1$-stabilization in motivic homotopy theory. This is the most "geometric" explanation I have found so far. Non-Tate twists? David's third comment may well be the best one can say.